# Python parsing based on values in string

Tags: python, parsing

I have a field that has 3 different values in any order I need to separate data into its own column not sure how to do this. In SQL Server, I would use `charindex` to find anchor location and extract what I need in Python I am not sure.

Here is a sample set:

```
3 bike, 4 cars, 2 mopeds
3 cars, 4 mopeds, 6 bike
1 mopeds, 2 bike, 3 cars
```

In SQL Server `substring(colname, charindex(' bike', colname, 0) - 1, 1)` will return all the values for bike. I would just change search string and return the other 2 values.

How would this be done in Python?

Comment: convert them to dicts

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent function to charindex is called `index`.  `value.index('bike')` gives you the index (0-based) of the first occurrence of 'bike' in the string `value`.

substring is done via slicing.   value[a:b] gives you all characters between index `a` (inclusive) and index `b` (exclusive).  Slicing has all sorts of other interesting uses, but you don't care about that.

Converting your code to Python should be straightforward.

Comment: nstr.index('bike')

Comment: nstr.value[nstr.index('bike')-2:nstr.index('bike')]

Comment: Tried lines above the index part works but the value part seems to error since string does not have a value method

Comment: Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't meaning literally `value`.  That was a stand-in for any string.  "hello"[1:3] = "el"

Comment: Ok that did it. so answer is nstr[nstr.index('bike')-2:nstr.index('bike')-1]

Comment: That works.  This is python, rather than SQL, so rather than calculating `nstr.index('bike')` twice, just calculate it once, put it in a variable, and then use that variable in the next equation.  It also makes your code less fragile, since there are fewer places to make a typo.

Comment: How would I re-write the solution in lambda I need to apply this to a column

Comment: Ah.  Didn't realize that.  Leave the code as it is.  It could be done as a lambda, but it's more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223879/discussion-between-leo-torres-and-frank-yellin).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question posted here. Didnt use Lambda but it got the job done
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29199115/Python-parse-with-lambda.html